# How to setState a item in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects.

I want to display these objects in my component and want to create a function to change `seen: 0` to `seen: 1` when I click on a button.

```
var historyNotif = [ 
   {id: 66, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Khouloud Ben Abddallah"},
   {id: 102, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez"},
   {id: 103, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez"},
]
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
isSeen() {
  this.setState(() => ({
    historyNotif: {
      ...this.state.historyNotif,
      seen: 1
    }
  }));
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: Post some code that you did

Comment: @PraveenGopal check the question i have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the notifications in component state, and mapping through this notifications in the render, you can generate some html, and trigger an event there to update the seen value.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    notifications: [
      { id: 66, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Khouloud Ben Abddallah" },
      { id: 102, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" },
      { id: 103, seen: 0, tourist_full_name: "Harry Paz Galvez" }
    ]
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    console.log(id);
    const updatedItems = this.state.notifications.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, seen: 1 };
      }
      return item;
    });
    this.setState({
      notifications: updatedItems
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.notifications.map(item => {
          return (
            <button key={item.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)}>
              {item.tourist_full_name}-{item.seen ? "SEEN" : "NOT SEEN"}>
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-browser-xhnzx)

Answer (score -2):

```
 isSeen=(id)=>{
    let {historyNotif}=this.state
    historyNotif.map(each=>each.id===id?each.seen=1:null)
    this.setState({historyNotif})
}
```

call this function and pass the id as argument ,which is existing

if you want to change the seen status of all objects.
you can do like

```
    isSeen=()=>{
       let {historyNotif}=this.state
       historyNotif.map(each=>each.seen=1);
       this.setState({historyNotif}
   }
```